# Flutter/Dart: How to make data load on the first tab when launching application?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Brief explanation:** I am creating an application that currently has three tabs. Upon loading the application, the data does not load on the first page. It just says "finding specials". When I swipe to the left, the information loads on the second and third tab, and only when I go BACK to the first tab does the information load there.[image: img]

Code:

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      title: "Local Hour application",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyTabs(), //Change to HomePage when wanting first clicking page
    )
);

class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  final String url = 'url-info-I-can\'t-disclose'; //API url
  List specials;
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);

    this.getSpecials().then((jsonSpecials) {
      setState(() {
        specials = jsonSpecials;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List> getSpecials() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(url + '/specials'),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.dehaze), //there's an "action" option for menus and stuff. "leading" for show
        title: specials == null ? Text("LOCAL HOUR",) : Text("Now with more special",),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: controller,
          tabs: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text("Today", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text("Tomorrow", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text("Next Day", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),),
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: controller,
        children: <Widget>[
          SecondPage(specials: specials),
          SecondPage(specials: specials),
          SecondPage(specials: specials),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Current issue: ** first page does not load on launching. Only when switching back and forth between tabs.

**My goal: ** to ensure that the data does load when launching the application and that I do not have to go back and forth just to see the first page.

Please let me know if I need to supply more information.

Comment: copied your code, added the missing parts and some more details, such as initialization and array type and a model. It worked for me. Follow the git https://github.com/ccastroelo/FlutterTabs

Comment: I can't figure out why mine doesn't work and yours does :/

Answer (score 5):

Michael, you should use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to make your future requests instead of requesting it in `initState()`. Below is how you can implement it. Since i don't have your api, i used a test api to demonstrate.

```
class MyTabs extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyTabsState createState() => MyTabsState();
}

class MyTabsState extends State<MyTabs> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'; //API url

  List specials;
  TabController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = TabController(vsync: this, length: 3);

//    this.getSpecials().then((jsonSpecials) {
//      setState(() {
//        specials = jsonSpecials;
//      });
//    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<List> getSpecials() async {
    var response = await http.get(Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    return jsonDecode(response.body);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: getSpecials(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data[0]);
            return MaterialApp(
                home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                  leading: Icon(Icons.dehaze),
                  //there's an "action" option for menus and stuff. "leading" for show
                  title: specials == null
                      ? Text("LOCAL HOUR")
                      : Text("Now with more special"),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                  bottom: TabBar(
                    controller: controller,
                    tabs: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child: Text("Today", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child:
                            Text("Tomorrow", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                        child:
                            Text("Next Day", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
              body: TabBarView(
                controller: controller,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),child: Text(snapshot.data[0]["title"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),child: Text(snapshot.data[1]["title"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                  Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),child: Text(snapshot.data[2]["title"], textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                ],
              ),
            ));
          } else {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }
}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, it unfortunately does not fix the issue since none of the pages load now and only the "finding specials" appear after a black screen with a loading circle. I feel the issue may be on one of the other files. Thanks again.

Comment: The issue could very well be in your `SecondPage`. No way to know without seeing the code which is why it's important to include relevant code or at least psuedo code. Above is an example to give you an idea but even if the issue is in `SecondPage`, you should use `FutureBuilder` as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Did you figure out this issue? I am having the exact same issue and i cant seem to find a solution to this, and its very annoying :/